# Koszul exact sequence of vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Let $S$ be any quasi-compact scheme and $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ on $S$ and $X = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ be its associated projective bundle with structure map $f : X \rightarrow S$. I want to show that why the below complex  is exact sequence of  vector bundles on $X$:  $ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(-r) \otimes \bigwedge^{r} f^{\ast}(\mathcal{E}) \rightarrow ... \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X}(-1) \otimes f^{\ast}(\mathcal{E}) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X} \rightarrow 0 $.

I know that it is complex because locally it is just koszul complex but I don't know why it is exact. Is it somehow the complex obtained from regular sequences? Any help would be great.

Comment: Question is local and thus you may assume $E$ is trivial. Rest of the calculation should be clear, since $X=\mathbb{P}^n_S$  where $n+1$ is the rank of $E$.

Comment: but how it is exact?

Comment: Use coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and see what the sequence looks like and use the regular sequence statement you alluded to.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks